# How to fix 'jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time' in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use jupyter-notebook in vs-code with the newest python extension, but always fail to launch jupyter notebook server

The jupyter notebook was installed by anoconda, and it works if i just type 'jupyter notebook' in cmd window.

Jupyter notebook failed to launch. Error: The Jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time

Comment: Hey Yi Wang. I'm a developer on this extension. One of the first things to check would be if you could launch from the command line, but I see that you've already done that. Could you look at the output of the console log of the developer tools console? That should have information that could help me diagnose this.

Comment: Sorry was on vacation, so the log was like:   Jupyter notebook failed to launch.  Error: The Jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time
onDidNotificationChange @ notificationsAlerts.ts:40

Comment: Get Interpreters, Class name = g, completed in 3ms, Arg 1: <Uri:d:\vs_codes>, Return Value: [{"architecture":3,"path":"D:\\Anaconda\\python.exe","version":{"options":{"loose":false,"includePrerelease":false},"loose":false,"raw":"3.7.1-final","major":3,"minor":7,"patch":1,"prerelease":["final"],"build":[],"version":"3.7.1-final"},"sysPrefix":"D:\\Anaconda","fileHash":"20a12b8440e36230d613de12438abb4e6ac0690237a50edca097d99cb8754fe032c98cbd29c443110cb9324af699d7fda347f8b70fb0c2cba4cb1cace7248ee6","companyDisplayName":"Anaconda, Inc.","type":"Conda","envName":"base","envPath":"D:\\Anaconda"}]

Comment: That looks like just part of the developer tools output. Do you happen to see anything in the console log (or you could send the whole log to ianhu [at] microsoft.com) about conda activation failing? We're dealing with a few different conda activation issue currently and my suspicion is that you are running into one of these. If it is conda issues, the last comment on this thread might be helpful:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8085

Comment: Hi, i'm not familiar with these stuff, so how do I get the log you said?

Comment: Sure. So if you open up VS Code you will see an option "Toggle Developer Tools" in the top level help menu. If you hit that it will open up a new window with developer tools that are associated with Visual Studio Code in it. On the top level menu of that window is "Console" next to "Elements" if you open this up and then try to run the notebook it will put a bunch of diagnostic info into this window. If you send this log to the address above I could take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yi Wang and I worked on debugging this over e-mail, but putting the answer back here on SO to make sure that anyone else hitting this issues sees it. The issue here was that the Python Path setting in vscode was set to point to pythonw.exe and not python.exe. I'm going to file an issue on the VSCode extension to provide a better warning in this situation.

Thanks again Yi Want for providing the logs that let us debug this.